# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression in <ng-form>

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, angularjs-directive, syntax-error

While using  i am getting following error.Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ng-form[name="form_name".
Can you please help me to solve this error.

Thank you,
Sachin Pawar

Answer (score 0):

From where did you read ng-form?

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>
```

Use above, 
Where

```
 - name = your form name 
 - ng-submit= will called on form submission
 - novalidate = it will stop default submission of html
```

Comment: [ngForm](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) is a directive

Comment: Hello Ritesh Arora i am trying to create dynamic fields in form using <ng-form> but while using it i am getting this error. Hierarchy is like below,
<Form>
<ng-form name="form_name">

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the error, but I think you misunderstood the syntax. The square brackets (`[`,`]`) mean that it is **optional**. So it's not `ng-form[name="form_name"]`

The actual syntax is:

```
<ng-form name="form_name"> ... </ng-form>"
```

Since it's a directive, it can also be:

```
<div ng-form name="form_name"> ... </div>
```